# Spark submit to pass unicode character

Tags: apache-spark, unicode

How to pass unicode character via spark-submit config?
while passing unicode character `\u001D` as csv delimeter via spark-submit, it throws below error:

> Unsupported special character for delimiter: \u001D. null()

```
spark-submit
  --conf spark.csv.delimeter="\u001D" \
```

below code works in spark-shell

```
val df = spark.read.option("sep","\u001D").option("header", "false").csv("PATH")
```

any option to pass unicode character via spark-submit

Comment: Have you tried to put the character instead of code? If you're in windows you can type it with wile holding Alt press 29. E.g. '↔'.